# Pulling a post from a category every third post

Tags: wordpress

I need some advice. Im trying to display a tweetpost every third posts displayed. I am pushing all the tweet posts into an array, and normal posts in to another array. Essentially what i want to do is if the counter = %3 then pull a post from the tweet array else pull it from the normal post array. Could someone show me how to do this? Or is there an alternative better way?

Much appreciated.

James

```
<?php 

$postarray = array ();
$tweetarray = array ();

while (have_posts()) : the_post();

if( in_category('tweets') ) {
    array_push($tweetarray, $post->ID);
} else {
    array_push($postarray, $post->ID);
}

++$counter;
if($counter %3) {

    //PULL AND DISPLAY TWEET POST FROM TWEETARRAY

} else {

    //PULL AND DISPLAY POST FROM POSTARRAY

}

endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Does it work? It seems sensible enough...

Also: I'm not a PHP guy, but do you need that to be:

if($counter % 3 == 0)

Comment: I dont know how to pull and display the posts inside the counter.

Comment: Do i need another wp query within there?

Answer (score 0):

use wp query

```
WP_Query('category_name=abc'&orderby=date&posts_per_page=5');
```